# Upload large files from system config not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, file-upload

I'm trying to Upload a zip archive to media from System/Configuration but when I choose a large file (e.g. 35MB) it redirect to Dashboard and I get the error

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

But if I upload a small file (e.g. 2MB) it is working fine.

In php.ini **upload_max_filesize** is **200MB**

Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I saw @rafal-kos answer I started to search what other configurations from *php.ini* can cause this problem and I found that the problem is not *max_input_vars*, the problem is **post_max_size=35M**, so if I change this allows me to upload files larger than 35MB.

Answer (score 1):

Please allow PHP to bigger number of input variables ($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE). This should be ok : **max_input_vars=10000**